integral curves and Lie group actions
given a vector field $ X $ on the tangent bundle $ T\mathcal{M} $ to a manifold $ \mathcal{M} $ the flow of the field $ X $ is the map $ \Phi_X : \mathbb{R} \times \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{M} $  defined as
$ \Phi_X (p, t) = \gamma_p (t) $
for any $ p \in \mathcal{M},    t \in \mathbb{R}$  and $ \gamma : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{M} $ being an integral curve of $ X $.
this basically says " give me a vector field, a point on $ M $ and a value of the parameter t and i'll give you the curve in $ M $ which passes through point p when the parameter equals t and is also an integral curve of $ X $"
according to the Wikipedia article on Fundamental vector fields, this flow is also an action of the additive Lie group $ (\mathbb{R}, +) $, i don't understand this statement. what leds us to conclude that the flow of a vector field (which is a collection of curves) is a Lie group action (which is an operation by some member of a Lie group)? also, what is this Lie group action acting on? points in $ \mathcal{M} $? tangent vectors on $ T\mathcal{M} $ ?
from what i understand, fundamental vector fields generalize this idea of the an action of a Lie group defining a tangent vector field on a manifold and viceversa to arbitrary Lie groups, not just the additive group. This same article claims the way to do so is by defining a smooth action of tan arbitrary Lie group as the map
$ A: G \times \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{M} $
then for any element $a$ of the Lie algebra $ \mathfrak{g} $
we have a vector field on $ \mathcal{M} $
$ X_p = \frac{d}{dt} [A(e^{at}, p)]_{t=0} $
where exactly does this generalization come from?

Suppose $X$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ with complete flow, meaning the flow map $\Phi:\Bbb{R}\times M\to M$ is defined everywhere. The meaning of the point $\Phi(t,x)\in M$ is that it is the point in the manifold you will end up if you start at the point $x\in M$, and ‘wait for time $t$’, purely under the influence of the vector field $X$ (it’s best to imagine dropping a small pebble in a river… which is also why the name flow is so apt).
This map $\Phi$ is literally the action map. The group here is $(\Bbb{R},+)$, the set being acted on is $M$, and $\Phi:\Bbb{R}\times M\to M$ is the action map. The fact that it really is an action map is encoded in the flow property $\Phi(t+s,x)=\Phi(t,\Phi(s,x))$, or simply $\Phi_{t+s}=\Phi_t\circ\Phi_s$.
So far we have described how to go from the complete vector field $X$ to the action map (i.e the flow); this is actually the difficult direction. We can also go the other way: given an action map $\Phi$, we can differentiate with respect to the first argument (‘time’) at $t=0$ (the neutral element of the additive group) to get the vector field $X$ (i.e for each $p\in M$, $X(p)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\Phi(t,p)\in T_pM$).
The other stuff you’re reading is just generalizing this idea from the super special Lie group $(\Bbb{R},+)$ to arbitrary Lie groups. But before you try to understand any of that, you had better understand the case of a single vector field and its flow properly.
